# JTable how to hide column in view but keep it in model for use it in background

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I have a `JTable` and am passing a data array into the `TableModel`. I wish to retain all columns in the data model as I need them all for background data processing, but I wish to show only some of the columns in the JTable.

How do I achieve this -- to remove a data column from the view (the visualized `JTable`) but not from the model (the `TableModel`)?

Comment: How to remove a column has been answered, however a better solution would be to create your own table model which provides the table with the relevant data.

Comment: You can hide columns dynamically, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793257/add-column-to-exiting-tablemodel/6796673#6796673) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793257/add-column-to-exiting-tablemodel/6798013#6798013).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JTable has

```
public void removeColumn(TableColumn aColumn)
```

Comment: I know remove column method. My doubt is how will it arrange data in columns. Say I have 3 columns. I have model data of 3 columns. I want to show only 2 columns. So how will it recognize which data to put in which column?

Comment: Methods of JTable to convert view column  index to model and opposite public int convertColumnIndexToModel(int viewColumnIndex) and public int convertColumnIndexToView(int modelColumnIndex)

Answer (score 1):

Override `getColumnCount` of the model to return less columns that there is. Then put your hidden columns as last columns of the model.