# Refresh a JTable using a JButton in another JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, jbutton

I've created two `JFrame`s. Frame 1 has a `JTable` and frame 2 has a `JButton`. The `JTable`  contains data from a MySQL table. What I want to do is this: when I click the `JButton` in frame 2, the `JTable` in frame 1 needs to be refreshed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Let your [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) export an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) that fires the `TableModelEvent` appropriate to any changes made. Use the `Action` to construct the button. When the button is clicked and the `Action` fires, any table listening to the table model will update automatically. There are related examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13500910/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513).

See also [*The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/230513)